# Is there a common conversion command to change NSString to sqlite compatible NSString

Tags: iphone

I found there are some special chars ',%.... not compatible to sqlite enquiry string.
Is there a common conversion command to change NSString to sqlite compatible NSString in objective-c?

Welcome any comment

Thanks

interdev

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't inject arbitrary strings into SQL. Use [parameters](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/bind_blob.html) instead.